# How to display my Array of Objects into my html page's table , individually, by their property name

Tags: javascript, html, frontend, javascript-objects, web-frontend

[Part of my JS file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ILLXF.png)

[My html file table where i have to display the properties](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GErMO.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**: I have applied my earlier code to your `searching` function:

Note: I added an `id` to the `tbody`:

```
<tbody id="myTBD">
```

```js
const getCafes = () => {
        const api =
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/debojyoti/places-fake-rest-api/master/cafes.json";
        return fetch(api).then((response) => {
            return response.json();

        });
    };
    var cafes = [];
    getCafes().then((result) => {
        cafes = Array.from(result.cafes);
        // console.log(cafes[1]);
    });

    const getPlaces = () => {
        const api =
            "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/debojyoti/places-fake-rest-api/master/places.json";
        return fetch(api).then((response) => {
            return response.json();
        });
    };
    var places = [];
    getPlaces().then((result) => {
        places = Array.from(result.places);
        // console.log(places[1]);
    });

    function searching() {
        let inp = document.getElementById("search").value;
        inp = inp.toUpperCase();

        var myTBD = document.getElementById("myTBD");
        // Clear table rows
        myTBD.innerHTML = '';

        var result = calc(inp);

        for (var i in result) {
            // Create an empty <tr> element and add it to the end of the table:
            var row = myTBD.insertRow(-1);

            // Insert new cells (<td> elements) at the 1st and 2nd position of the "new" <tr> element:
            var rowIndex = 0;      
            row.insertCell(rowIndex++).innerHTML = result[i].street_no;
            row.insertCell(rowIndex++).innerHTML = result[i].name;
            row.insertCell(rowIndex++).innerHTML = result[i].locality;
            row.insertCell(rowIndex++).innerHTML = result[i].postal_code;
            row.insertCell(rowIndex++).innerHTML = result[i].lat;
            row.insertCell(rowIndex++).innerHTML = result[i].long;
        }
    }

    function calc(inp) {
        arr = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < cafes.length; i++) {
            if (cafes[i].name.toUpperCase().startsWith(inp) === true) {
                let id1 = cafes[i].location_id;
                //   console.log('hi:'+inp);
                for (let j = 0; j < places.length; j++) {
                    if (places[j].id === id1) {
                        var obj = Object.assign({}, places[j]);
                        obj["name"] = cafes[i].name;
                        delete obj.id;
                        arr.push(obj);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <title>California Cafe Directory</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="page.css">
</head>

<body>

    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12" id="header-wrapper">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-12" id="header">
                            <h2>California Cafe Directory</h2>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-12" id="search-wrapper">
                            <input id="search" type="text" oninput="searching()" placeholder="Search your favorite cafes!">
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-12" id="table-wrapper">
                        <table>
                            <thead>
                                <tr class="table100-head">
                                    <th class="column1">S No</th>
                                    <th class="column2">Cafe Name</th>
                                    <th class="column3">Address</th>
                                    <th class="column4">Postal Code</th>
                                    <th class="column5">Lat</th>
                                    <th class="column6">Long</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="myTBD">
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="column1">1</td>
                                    <td class="column2"><span id="col2"></span></td>
                                    <td class="column3">45250 Worth Avenue, Unit A</td>
                                    <td class="column4">201619</td>
                                    <td class="column5">36.1152</td>
                                    <td class="column6">117.521</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="column1">2</td>
                                    <td class="column2">Bazaar Cafe</td>
                                    <td class="column3">45250 Worth Avenue, Unit A</td>
                                    <td class="column4">201619</td>
                                    <td class="column5">36.1152</td>
                                    <td class="column6">117.521</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="column1">3</td>
                                    <td class="column2">Bazaar Cafe</td>
                                    <td class="column3">45250 Worth Avenue, Unit A</td>
                                    <td class="column4">201619</td>
                                    <td class="column5">36.1152</td>
                                    <td class="column6">117.521</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="column1">4</td>
                                    <td class="column2">Bazaar Cafe</td>
                                    <td class="column3">45250 Worth Avenue, Unit A</td>
                                    <td class="column4">201619</td>
                                    <td class="column5">36.1152</td>
                                    <td class="column6">117.521</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="column1">5</td>
                                    <td class="column2">Bazaar Cafe</td>
                                    <td class="column3">45250 Worth Avenue, Unit A</td>
                                    <td class="column4">201619</td>
                                    <td class="column5">36.1152</td>
                                    <td class="column6">117.521</td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="column1">6</td>
                                    <td class="column2">Bazaar Cafe</td>
                                    <td class="column3">45250 Worth Avenue, Unit A</td>
                                    <td class="column4">201619</td>
                                    <td class="column5">36.1152</td>
                                    <td class="column6">117.521</td>
                                </tr>

                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="solution.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Maybe I should be more specific...I am fetching the details via an API call(link to Api in the js file) and then performing some operations in the calc() function of my code, which returns an Array containing Objects with my desired properties...Till here everything works fine!
But now I have to destructure it and display it into the table ,with each property value destructured into its individual table column...How can I do that...I am really struck here..help me out..
My code:
[link](https://codepen.io/1canis-lupus1/pen/poyvGVE)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your array of objects is something like this:

```
[
  {id: 1, name: 'Bazaar Coffee', address: '45250 Worth Avenue, Unit A', zip_code: 201619, latitude: 36.11512, longitude: 117.521}
  ...
]
```

You can do something like:

```
var table = document.getElementById('table-body')
arrayOfObj.forEach((obj)=>{
    var tds = ''
  // Build every <td> and append to tds string
  /* for (var k in obj){
    tds += `<td class='${k}'>${obj[k]}</td>\n`
  } */
  // If your keys are unordered you can just define all the tds in the row. See this as a template.
  tds = `<td class='column-id'>${obj.id}</td>
    <td class='column-name'>${obj.name}</td>
    <td class='column-address'>${obj.address}</td>
    <td class='column-zip_code'>${obj.zip_code}</td>
    <td class='column_latitude'>${obj.latitude}</td>
    <td class='column_longitude'>${obj.longitude}</td>
  `
  // <tr> Complete! Append to table!
  var objTr = `<tr>${tds}</tr>`
  table.innerHTML += objTr
});
```

Check out this snippet:
https://jsfiddle.net/sergioxga/brtncx96/7/

```js
// Assuming your array of objects is something like this:
var arrayOfObj = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Bazaar Coffee', address: '45250 Worth Avenue, Unit A', zip_code: 201619, latitude: 36.11512, longitude: 117.521},
  {id: 1, name: 'Bazaar Coffee', address: '45250 Worth Avenue, Unit A', zip_code: 201619, latitude: 36.11512, longitude: 117.521},
  {id: 1, name: 'Bazaar Coffee', address: '45250 Worth Avenue, Unit A', zip_code: 201619, latitude: 36.11512, longitude: 117.521}
]
var table = document.getElementById('table-body')
arrayOfObj.forEach((obj)=>{
  var tds = ''
  // Build every <td> and append to tds string
  /* for (var k in obj){
    tds += `<td class='${k}'>${obj[k]}</td>\n`
  } */
  // If your keys are unordered you can just define all the tds in the row. You can see this as a template.
  tds = `<td class='column-id'>${obj.id}</td>
    <td class='column-name'>${obj.name}</td>
    <td class='column-address'>${obj.address}</td>
    <td class='column-zip_code'>${obj.zip_code}</td>
    <td class='column_latitude'>${obj.latitude}</td>
    <td class='column_longitude'>${obj.longitude}</td>
  `
  // <tr> Complete! Append to table!
  var objTr = `<tr>${tds}</tr>`
  table.innerHTML += objTr
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<table>
<thead>
  <tr>
  <td>ID</td>
  <td>Name</td>
  <td>Address</td>
  <td>ZipCode</td>
  <td>Latitude</td>
  <td>Longitude</td>
  </tr>
  
</thead>
<tbody id='table-body'>
  
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: I did this and now I can see the data on my html page..thanks to you.

[link]https://codepen.io/1canis-lupus1/pen/poyvGVE

But I am facing further issues in this:

I want to display them in my table based on their property-name...right now it is coming in the order it is present in the object.I can see you used classname and set it to the individual property names..but how can I assign it my HTML tables as well i.e. based on classname..and not randomly

Comment: @ShubhamChoudhary If the keys on your objects are unordered, instead of iterating over the keys in the object to build the tds of your row, you can just specifically define how you would like the tds (or even all the row), when using backticks (`) you are basically declaring a template, which I think is just exactly what you need https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals.
I just updated the code in my response :)

Comment: Thanks for this edit..I got an insight on how I was getting it wrong and now have multiple ways of correcting to..thanks to you all!!! UPVOTED!